# could not find function "as.triangle"

Tags: r

I need to transform data table into triangle form.
So, I download **the ChainLadder** package.Then, I import the data from the table. You can see it as below:

```
> head(triangle.csv)
  année dev montant
1  2009   1    2147
2  2009   2    3365
3  2009   3    2129
4  2009   4    1070
5  2009   5       0
6  2009   6     300
```

I need to convert this table into triangle form like :
this table constructed in Excel

[image]

So I wrote this code:

```
data<-as.triangle(triangle.csv)
```

But an Error is shown:

> Error in as.triangle(triangle.csv) :    could not find function
>   "as.triangle"

How do I resolve this problem please?

Comment: Have you loaded the package i.e. `library(ChainLadder)`

Comment: @akrun, yes of course, I called the library(ChainLadder)

Comment: Did the `library` call produce an error? What happens when you run `ChainLadder::as.triangle(triangle.csv)`?

Comment: This is weird. I come to install the package, and `as.triangle(triangle.csv, origin="année", dev="dev", "montant")` works for me. Could you please post the result of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @EuGENE,oh thank you very much it works for  me!!

Comment: Ok, let's make it a formal answer so it can better help others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is actually just specify the arguments in the function. You should write:

```
as.triangle(triangle.csv, origin="année", dev="dev", "montant")
```

Remember you can also specify the package name, as pointed out by @Paul in the comments, as: `ChainLadder::as.triangle()`.

EDIT: for future issues, remember to practice with the examples that you can find in the man pages (eg .`?as.triangle`).